# In jvectormap is there a way to show individual us states on page load?

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I am new to using jvectormap.  I was wondering if there was a way to show individual US states on page load?  I have USA drill down map working but need to be able to show specific states such as Colorado for example without having to zoom in from the larger map of the USA.  I know there are ways to create your own individual state maps from vector files but just thought I would ask here to see if it was possible to do that using the map that jvector provides for the US before I went through that process.  Any help is much appreciated.  (I do have the individual state map js files that have county infomation but have not yet figured out how to use them.)

Below is the script I am using that is currently showing the default US map for drilling down to specific states:

```
$(function () {
    var map1;
    new jvm.MultiMap({
        container: $('#map1'),
        maxLevel: 1,
        mapUrlByCode: function (code, multiMap) {
            return 'assets/us/jquery-jvectormap-data-' + code.toLowerCase() + '-' + multiMap.defaultProjection + '-en.js';
        },
        main: {
            map: 'us_lcc_en'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try deleting the _en from your map declaration

Comment: Thanks for your response :)  I tried that but currently it is still showing full US map which I expected since this is pretty much the code they show in the documentation for the out of the box drill down US map.  I guess I dont really know how to use the code for the individual states or the focusOn property to initialize the map viewport scale and position with.

Answer (score 1):

OK I have found the answer to my own question here. :) I found the individual state maps provided in the tests>assets>us files provided in the full download of jvectormap have names at the beginning such as 'us-ak_lcc_en' for Alaska in the jquery-jvectormap-data-us-ak-lcc-en.js file. When I included that name instead of 'us_lcc_en' in the map declaration it loads the state level map of Alaska for example. Its actually pretty cool too since you can then click on a county and zoom in to that county since I am using the drill down map